# Checking if a ViewController on Navigation Stack exists

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have this code here to check on the existence of the `ViewController`. And unfortunately it doesn't work. The thing is, it is executed *at the moment* of another VC popping from the `Navigation Stack`:

```
- (void) leftViewDidHide{
    if ([((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).frontViewController.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]) {
    SGServerListViewController *sample = [[[((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).frontViewController.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [sample.serverTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

The app crashes with an exception breakpoint pointing me to the line with an `if` statement. Any ideas on what could be wrong here? I'm just trying to check if this `VC` is there and if it is - execute the code.

Comment: you want recent navigation controller?

Comment: What's the error message? Out of bounds? Then don't check for the object, but for the number of associated viewcontrollers. E.g. `if (...viewcontrollers count] == 1)`

Comment: @SAE Right, it says "out of bounds". Make it an answer so I can accept it. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) leftViewDidHide{

if ([((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).frontViewController.navigationController.viewControllers count] == 1) {

         SGServerListViewController *sample = [[[((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).frontViewController.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
         [sample.serverTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NSArray *viewControlles = [self.navigationController.viewControllers];

for (int i = 0 ; i <viewControlles.count; i++){ 
  if ([YourVC isKindOfClass:[viewControlles objectAtIndex:i]]) {
          //Execute your code
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 NSArray *controllerArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers];
//will get all the controllers added to UINavigationController.

    for (id controller in controllerArray)
   { 
      // iterate through the array and check for your controller
      if ([controller isKindOfClass:[checkYourController class]]) 
          {
              //do your stuff here
          }
    }
```

just for an idea `containsObject:` method of `NSArray` class might also work.

Answer (score 3):

```
-(BOOL)isControllerAlreadyOnNavigationControllerStack{

    for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:Controller.class]) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:NO];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}


if (![self isControllerAlreadyOnNavigationControllerStack]) {
    //push controller 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that (checking if a ViewController on Navigation Stack exists) with this code:

```
if navigationController?.viewControllers.count > 1 {
    for root in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
        if root is ViewController {
           let i = root as? ViewController
            i?.table.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *viewControlles = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

for (int i = 0 ; i <viewControlles.count; i++){
    if ([[viewControlles objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[RequiredViewController class]]) {

        //Enter your code

    }
}
```